# How can I change the language of the website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Can I possibly change the language of the website using javascript and this select code?

````
<select class = "log">

    <option value = "EN">English</option>
    <option value = "ES">Español</option>
    <option value = "DE">Deutsch</option>
    <option value = "FR">Français</option>

</select>```
````

Comment: You need to have your [i18n](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n) files for each language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please look up i18n for best js translation

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class = "log">

    <option value = "EN">English</option>
    <option value = "ES">Español</option>
    <option value = "DE">Deutsch</option>
    <option value = "FR">Français</option>

</select>
<div id="paragraph">
</div>
<script>
const texte = {EN: 'Good Morning',
         ES: 'Buenos Dias',
         DE: 'Guten Tag',
         FR: 'Bonjour'}
const language = document.querySelector('select');
const paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');

function show() {
  paragraph.textContent = texte[language.value];
}
language.addEventListener('change', show)

</script>
```